# Rebase a decimal field of an IEnumerable against two other fields in a better & fast way

Tags: c#, linq

Got a situation here, though I have a few ways to solve the problem but I'm very much feeling that it's not the best way to solve as I'm doing it now. Let me try to explain my problem first. From Database I get an IEnumerable of NavReturnModelSP where NavReturnModelSP is a simple model class like

```
public class NavReturnModelSP
{
    public string Scheme_Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double ReInvest_Nav { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to first order the set by Scheme_Name & Date & then need to rebase each Scheme & Date pair value to the base of 100 for proper comparison between schemes from the very first date. **I CAN'T CHANGE THE DATABASE OUTPUT**. Below is a picture for your referance, Hope it'll explain you the problem better.

[image: The problem]

And I'm solving it now just by looping through....
where 'data' is the IEnumerable of NavReturnModelSP

```
var preModel = data.OrderBy(x => x.Scheme_Name).ThenBy(x => x.Date).ToList();
var preScheme = "";
var firstNav = 0d;
for (int i = 0; i < preModel.Count(); i++)
{
    if (preModel[i].Scheme_Name != preScheme)
    {
        firstNav = preModel[i].ReInvest_Nav;
        preModel[i].ReInvest_Nav = 100;
    }
    else
    {
         if (preModel[i - 1].ReInvest_Nav != 0) // Just a check, nothing special.
             preModel[i].ReInvest_Nav = 100 * preModel[i].ReInvest_Nav / firstNav;
    }
    preScheme = preModel[i].Scheme_Name;
}
```

Now I have 'preModel' with the rebased data in the ReInvest_Nav column. But I feel that I'm not using the proper power of the CPU & I can use Parallal programming / PLINQ to minimize the time frame as for 100000 rows for loop will be quite slow. Can someone please guide me for that.

Thanks & Happy New Year :)
Sanjay

Comment: I don't see the point.  Pulling 100000 rows of data out of the dbase is *very* slow, optimizing the code that uses the data would make the entire operation, maybe, 0.1% faster.  Always profile first.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand that, but the problem is The SP that returns this type of data is of some other vendor that I can't modify :( and 100000 is the max it may vary from 2000 to that limit.

Comment: That's entirely not the point.  Of course the dbase is slow.  The point is that you are wasting time improving code without ever being able to see the difference.  You haven't **measured** that your existing code is the bottleneck.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right, my bottleneck is the wrong way return from DB, but that I can't change & then I found this looping problem interesting & just want to solve it in a better way as far as possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var preModel = data.GroupBy(x => x.Scheme_Name)
                   .Select(x => new {
                                      Scheme_Name = x.Key, 
                                      Max = x.Max(m => m.ReInvest_Nav), 
                                      Data = x
                                    })
                   .SelectMany(x => x.Data.Select(y => new {
                                       y.Scheme_Name, 
                                       y.Date, 
                                       y.ReInvest_Nav, 
                                       Rebased = y.ReInvest_Nav / x.Max * 100
                                     }))
                   .OrderBy(x => x.Scheme_Name)
                   .ThenBy(x => x.Date)
                   .ToList();
```

I can't promise this will be any faster, but it avoids explicit loops.

Comment: That's a big LINQ :) going through it now... will update you. Meanwhile I'm thinking something like. The Scheme & Date combination rows doesn't depend on each other, So each set of rows against Scheme & Date combination can be processed in a parallal way...

Comment: @user1841842 - Certainly doable.  You'd just need to do the `GroupBy`, and then for each key, spin off a new thread.

Comment: Can you please give a hint code. Do I need to use AsParallel() after the groupby by Scheme & Date?

Comment: @user1841842 - I'm not sure. I don't work with PLINQ very often.  Let me play with it a bit and get back to you.

Comment: @user1841842 - I believe that adding the `AsParallel()` right after the `GroupBy` would be sufficient, and that it'll automatically make the rest run as a series of threads.  At least, I don't get any errors in doing that.  Give it a try!